# Java fx combobox reset issue

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox, javafx, javafx-2

When I try to clear a combobox using following code:

code :

```
public class ComboController implements Initializable
{

@FXML
ComboBox firstcombobox=new ComboBox();
@FXML
ComboBox secondcombobox=new ComboBox();
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    firstcombobox.getItems().add("firabc");
    firstcombobox.getItems().add("firbcd");

    secondcombobox.getItems().add("seccde");
    secondcombobox.getItems().add("secdef");
}
@FXML
public void firstcomboboxAction()
{
    secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    secondcombobox.getItems().clear();
    System.out.println(firstcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
}

public void secondcomboboxAction()
{
    System.out.println(secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    System.out.println("my name is vinay");
}

}
```

It automatically calls action event

first i selected "seccde" from second combobox
then i selected "firabc" from first combobox

output i received is:

```
seccde
my name is vinay
null
my name is vinay
firabc
```

but it should have been :

```
seccde
my name is vinay

firabc  [with an empty firstcombobox]
```

Fxml :

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.ComboController">
<ComboBox fx:id="firstcombobox" onAction="#firstcomboboxAction"  >
<ComboBox fx:id="secondcombobox" onAction="#secondcomboboxAction" >
```

Comment: what do you want? it works perfectly!!

Comment: I am making a database search.when i try to clear these comboboxes, which then calls its associated actions automatically leading to null poiner error as i have removed that search condition

Comment: show your whole code first!!

Comment: secondcomboboxAction() should not have been called

Comment: but to how do you call both this method? where is your FXML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is exactly what you should expect.

First you select something in the second combo box. This invokes the handler for the second combo box, giving the output

```
seccde
my name is vinay
```

Then you select an item in the first combo box. This invokes the handler for the first combo box. The handler for that combo box first clears all items from the second combo box, which as a side effect sets the value property of the second combo box to null. This causes the action handler for the second combo box to be invoked, generating the output

```
null
my name is vinay
```

The handler for the second combo box then generates the output

```
firabc
```

and of course at this point the second combo box will have no items in it.

This is all in accordance with the Javadocs for the ComboBox. In particular, the [docs for the onAction handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#onActionProperty) describe the handler as follows:

> The ComboBox action, which is invoked whenever the ComboBox value
>   property is changed. This may be due to the value property being
>   programmatically changed, when the user selects an item in a popup
>   list or dialog, or, in the case of editable ComboBoxes, it may be when
>   the user provides their own input (be that via a TextField or some
>   other input mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for reseting your combo box after click on button event.

For Eg.

```
yourresetbutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) { 

          firstcombobox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
          firstcombobox.getItems().clear();

          secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
          secondcombobox.getItems().clear();
          }             
      });
```

Check with this to reset combo box.

Thanks..

Comment: sir, first set value to second combobox, do not select value in first combobox and then try to reset its value in first combobox action it is automatically calling second combobox action

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using changeListener.

```
public class ComboController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    ComboBox firstcombobox=new ComboBox();
    @FXML
    ComboBox secondcombobox=new ComboBox();
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) 
    {
        // adding elements to comboboxes
        firstcombobox.getItems().add("firabc");
        firstcombobox.getItems().add("firbcd");

        secondcombobox.getItems().add("seccde");
        secondcombobox.getItems().add("secdef");

        // adding action to first combobox
        firstcombobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener(new firstcomboboxAction());

        // adding action to second combobox
        secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener(new secondcomboboxAction());

    }

class firstcomboboxAction implements ChangeListener<String>
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,String oldValue, String newValue) {

         if(newValue!=null)
         {
                  secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                  secondcombobox.getItems().clear();
                  System.out.println(firstcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
         }
}


class secondcomboboxAction implements ChangeListener<String>
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,String oldValue, String newValue) 
    {
        System.out.println(secondcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println("my name is vinay");
    }
}
}
```

FXML:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
fx:controller="application.ComboController">
<ComboBox fx:id="firstcombobox"  >
<ComboBox fx:id="secondcombobox"  >
```

Output:

```
seccde
my name is vinay

firabc  [with an empty firstcombobox]
```